# SQL Server stored procedure errors when called from ASP.NET

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a simple stored procedure that checks for duplicate entries when a string is entered on an ASP.NET web page.

Web page contains a combo box, with the idea that a user can tell while typing if the entry already exists, so contains some data for autocomplete, however, if you try to ADD a duplicate, obviously want to catch and prevent the insert.

```
<ajaxToolkit:ComboBox
    ID="IngredientInput"
    runat="server" 
    ShowToggleImage="false" 
    AutoPostBack="false"
    AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend"
    DataSourceID="DsIngredients"
    DataTextField="IngredientName"
    DataValueField="IngredientID"
    MaxLength="0"
    >
     </ajaxToolkit:ComboBox>

<asp:Button id="Button3" class="btn btn-light" runat="server" OnClick="EditButton_Click" Text="Add" />
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="DsIngredients" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DB_A0C2A7_KessiesKitchenConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Ingredients]"
    InsertCommand="InsertIngredient" 
    InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="IngredientName" ControlID="IngredientInput" PropertyName="text"></asp:ControlParameter>
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

SQL data source is called from code behind on the button

```
protected void EditButton_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    DsIngredients.Insert();
    IngredientInput.Text = null;
    IngredientInput.SelectedValue = null;
    GVIngredientResults.DataBind();
}
```

The stored procedure is being called, 2 versions of, both return the same result.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertIngredient]
    @IngredientName NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @counter INT 

    SET @counter = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Ingredients] WHERE IngredientName LIKE @IngredientName)

    IF @counter = 0
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Ingredients] ([IngredientName])
        VALUES (@IngredientName)
    ELSE
        RETURN
END
GO
```

Second version

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Ingredients] WHERE IngredientName = @IngredientName)
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Ingredients] ([IngredientName])
    VALUES (@IngredientName)
ELSE
    RETURN
```

In both cases, I feel the else is redundant, however included for testing purposes. I have been running some code on SQL Server, with correct results. Both commented and non commented.

```
DECLARE @IngredientName NVARCHAR(50)

-- DECLARE @counter INT
SET @IngredientName = 'Red Cabbage'
-- SET @counter = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Ingredients] WHERE IngredientName = @IngredientName)

   -- IF @counter = 0
   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Ingredients] WHERE IngredientName = @IngredientName)
       INSERT INTO [dbo].[Ingredients] ([IngredientName])
       VALUES (@IngredientName)
   ELSE 
       RETURN
```

However, when I run the ASP.NET web page, and enter a duplicate string value, it is inserting the `recordID` for the original value, instead of returning with no insert. once it has done this, entering the same duplicate value has no effect.

A live demo of the issue is available, just enter an existing value at http://kessieskitchen.zedicussoftware.com/IngredientManagement and it will insert the recordID of the original entry.

Probably something simple I have missed, but I cannot work out why this is occurring

Comment: Your question is clear but confuse at the same time. Why does it insert the recordId instead of the @IngredientName?

Comment: Thats what I would like to know. nowhere in the code i have written SHOULD it insert the "ingredientID" .. errm, hmm maybe if I remove the  DataValueField="IngredientID" from the combobox.

Comment: And as simple as that, it appears to have solved the issue, it apparently was taking the DataValueField and inserting, instead of the Text value i was expecting.

Comment: Good to know it's resolved

Comment: My question now is, why did SQL controlparam not take the "text" value of the control, as requested, but the "DataValueField" from databound control.